# Is there a significant difference between [web-crawler] and [web-scraping]?

Tags: discussion

Is there a significant difference between [web-crawler] and [web-scraping]?

To Scrape, you gotta Crawl?

Well, you could scrape only one webpage, but why do that? That's better if you regex the page source or something?

Comment: You can crawl sites without scraping. You can scrape specific pages without crawling the site if you know the URLs you want to scrape.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there are significant differences. The terms are related, not the same.

Crawling: traversing a series of URLs, possibly using scraping to discover more links (but links can be discovered by other means, like from a [sitemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps)).

Scraping: parsing the HTML and / or other resources to mine it for specific information; that doesn’t necessarily including links and doesn’t mean crawling was used to locate the target resources being scraped. If I copy the URL of this page into my code and use that to scrape this page no crawling was done.

Regex is just one of the tools used to scrape. One is usually better of by starting with a HTML parsed, see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)